# Terminal.app: changing shell behavior problem?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

I'm having problems setting Terminal.app's default shell.  It appears to work using a command line utility which sets the shell for the account, however not in Terminal.app's dialog which is for each session.  I find that if I set the shell system with with 'chsh', the $SHELL variable in Terminal.app correctly reflects the shell.  If I change the shell in Terminal.app only, $SHELL does not correctly reflect the shell, however the shell appears to be the correct shell running.  I tried this on a temp account to rule out other interactions and it has the same behavior.

Here is a use case:
When I run in Terminal.app:

```
$ chsh -s /bin/ksh
```

and invoke Terminal.app, the shell is correctly changed:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/ksh
```

The problem is if try similar through Terminal.app->Preferences->General->Shells open with->Command->/bin/ksh

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Yet when I try command completions with TAB, it reflects ksh behavior.

Therefore, my suspicion is there is something overriding the SHELL environment variable where it is always SHELL=/bin/bash, despite the shell being different than that.

Does anyone know if Apple has a bug here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following information is taken from

- [SHELL environment variable still points to zsh after using bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/522907) and
- [What sets the $SHELL environment variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277944)

on Unix & Linux, which applies to macOS as well.

You *are* running the Korn shell if the Terminal preference is set to `/bin/ksh`. The output

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

is misleading because the `SHELL` variable is set by the login process to

> The user's shell, as specified by the password database.

(On macOS it is a user database and not the `/etc/passwd` file as on Linux, where that information is stored, but that does not matter.)

You can type

```
$ echo $0
-ksh
```

or

```
$ echo $KSH_VERSION
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
```

to verify that you are running the Korn shell.

Setting the shell via

```
$ chsh -s /bin/ksh
```

sets the login shell in the user database, and then `SHELL` is set accordingly:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/ksh
```